# Merge insert with select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

This works for me

```
MERGE Table1 AS tgt
USING
(
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        *
    FROM
        Table2,
        (
            SELECT
                itmid
            FROM
                Table3
            WHERE
                id = @id
        ) as a
    WHERE
        id = @id
) AS src
ON ( tgt.id = src.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET qty = qty + @qty
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT itmid
    VALUES itmid;
```

But when i change like this, its not working, showing error near last `select`

```
MERGE Table1 AS tgt
USING
(
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        *
    FROM
        Table2
    WHERE
        id = @id
) AS src
ON ( tgt.id = src.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET qty = qty + @qty
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT itmid
    SELECT itmid FROM Table3 WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: All additional fields should be passed in USING clause (add subselect column or join another table)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

```
<merge_not_matched>::=
{
    INSERT [ ( column_list ) ] 
        { VALUES ( values_list )
        | DEFAULT VALUES }
}
```

The syntax with `INSERT` *from* `SELECT` like:

```
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT itmid SELECT itmid FROM Table3 WHERE id=@id;
```

**Is not allowed!**

I would try to solve your problem doing another merge with `Table3`.

Answer (score -5):

do this

```
 MERGE Table1 AS tgt
 USING (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table2
        WHERE id = @id) AS src
ON (tgt.id = src.id)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET qty = qty + @qty
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (itmid) 
                 SELECT itmid FROM Table3 WHERE id=@id;
```

Should work fine according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Sorry I interpreted it wrong and my original answer would stand which was

```
MERGE Table1 AS tgt
     USING (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table2
            WHERE id = @id) AS src
    ON (tgt.id = src.id)
                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET qty = qty + @qty
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (itmid) values (SELECT top 1 itmid FROM Table3 WHERE id=@id);
```

As merge insert takes one insert at a time and it might fail for multiple inserts.

Comment: This syntax does not exist as part of the merge statement. I also couldn't imagine how the query plan would look like.

Comment: INSERT () VALUES (SELECT...) is not valid for the MERGE syntax. You cannot "trick" it. Please delete this as you've obviously not tested your code.

Comment: This syntax does not exist