# Incorrect syntax near Keyword Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have tried my best to fix this, but nothing so far.

This code gives me the error:

```
MERGE Monitoring.MonitoringDataFilter T
                USING
                (
                    SELECT
                        MonitoringDataFilterID AS MonitoringDataFilterID
                )S 
                    ON T.MonitoringDataFilterID = S.MonitoringDataFilterID
                WHEN MATCHED
                THEN
                    UPDATE
                    SET
                        MonitoringDataId            = @MonitoringDataId,
                        FilterTypeId                = @FilterTypeID,
                        CreatedBy                   = @UserLogin,
                        CreatedDate                 = GETDATE()
                WHEN NOT MATCHED
                THEN    
                    INSERT 
                    // Error Near this     Monitoring.MonitoringDataFilter 
                    (
                        MonitoringDataID,   
                        FilterTypeID,       
                        CreateBy,
                        CreatedDate,            
                    )
                    SELECT 
                            MD.MonitoringDataID,
                            @FilterTypeID,
                            @UserLogin,
                            GETDATE() 
                    FROM 
                            Monitoring.MonitoringData MD 
                    WHERE 
                    MD.MonitoringID = @MonitoringID;
```

Can I get help with some idea of how to fix this?

Comment: There is a stray comma after CreatedDate that could be causing you issues.

Comment: nope dude @IrishGeek82 it always appear `Incorrect syntax near 'Monitoring' ` , I don't what is that

Comment: I assume that the title was supposed to be the error you're getting, can you update the question accordingly?

Comment: I'll keep looking into it:)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that just because the error says `near 'Monitoring'` doesn't mean that the problem has to be right next to that line. It could be a few lines off.

Comment: Must it be `MERGE INTO Monitoring.MonitoringDataFilter T`

Comment: You can't write an `INSERT...SELECT` inside a `MERGE`. The `INSERT` has to be a `VALUES()` style one. The only source for your data should be the source table (or query) specified after `USING`.

Comment: There was a another questions regarding Merge with INSERT...SELECT here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646585/merge-insert-with-select-statement  in which they arrived at the same answer as Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed out [Schema Name]

```
Database_Name.Schema_Name.Table_Name

i.e. Monitoring.dbo.MonitoringDataFilter
```